# How to get this image not to get out of parents div

Tags: jquery

I got this code i cant figure out how to not to exceed parents div border.

The object its draggable and i resize it with the slider but i cant figure how to do it, thanks.

```
 $(document).on("input change",'.image-slider', function() {

    $('#timelineBGload-perfil').draggable();

    var slider = parseInt($(this).val());

    var height1 = $('#timelineBGload-perfil').height();
    var width1 = $('#timelineBGload-perfil').width();

    var percent1 = width1 / 600 *  100;

        var jeje = slider - 191;
        var jeje2 = slider - 191;

         $('#timelineBGload-perfil').css({'width': slider,'height':'auto'});

         $('#timelineBGload-perfil').css({'left': '-'+ jeje +'px','top': '-'+ jeje2 +'px'});

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fypqgym1/

Comment: Its working on jsfiddle.

Comment: its working until resize

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: No still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account the position of the image before you move it.  I added this key section to your logic:

```
var previousLeft = $('#timelineBGload-perfil').css('left');
var previousTop = $('#timelineBGload-perfil').css('top');
```

Here is a working example with some optimizations:
https://jsfiddle.net/fypqgym1/11/

You will need to work with the image and the dimensions to make it however you need.  You might also add an initialization step where you align things the way you want on startup.

Comment: Thanks it works fine, just i need the image not get out of the parent div when i resize the image higher and slower

Comment: Wow a year+ after the original answer.  Looks like you should check the computed `left` and `top` values and simply constrain them to minimum and maximum values via `Math.max` and `Math.min`.